# MySQL Implementation of Consecutive Streak of Dates

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I need a MySQL implementation of the brilliant code answering this question:

[Consecutive Streak of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812397/consecutive-streak-of-dates)

I have the exact same problem - but (as I understand it) MySQL does not support `DENSE_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. I have tried using a month-based version of the query found here: [forums.mysql.com: Group By Consecutive Dates](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,308991,318924#msg-318924) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027104/getting-collections-of-consecutive-dates) and  but the query bogs down on 300,000 not very consecutive records for 6,000 'users'

Thanks muchly

Comment: AFAIK such thing can only be done with recursive (WITH RECURSIVE statement and x=x+1 (consecutive) condition) queries or equivalent, and MySQL does not support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So this answer should give you everything you need apart from the 'months since last range end' field. Maybe you can build on it and figure it out yourself ;-). I've renamed the `#data` table (referred to in the Consecutive Streak of Dates post) as as `payment`:

```
CREATE TABLE payment
(
Contact_reference VARCHAR(55),
Date_payment DATETIME,
Payment_value double
);

INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2003-06-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2004-06-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2004-12-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-04-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-05-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-06-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-07-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-08-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-09-08',12.82);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-10-10',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-11-10',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2005-12-10',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2006-01-10',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2006-02-10',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2006-02-28',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2006-04-12',12.8205);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2006-05-10',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-06-11',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-07-10',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-08-09',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-09-10',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-10-09',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-11-09',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2007-12-10',19.2308);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES ('18EC3CD2-3065-4FF4-BE40-000004228590','2008-01-10',19.2308);

select Contact_reference,
consecStartDate as Range_start,
max(Date_payment) as Range_end,
count(*) as Payments,
sum(Payment_value) as value
from
(
select Contact_reference,
case when year(Date_payment)*12 + month(Date_payment) - @curMonthNum  <= 1 and @curRef = Contact_reference then 'Y' else 'N' end as consec,
case when year(Date_payment)*12 + month(Date_payment) - @curMonthNum  <= 1 and @curRef = Contact_reference then @consecStartDate := @consecStartDate else @consecStartDate := Date_payment  end as consecStartDate,
Date_payment,Payment_value,
@curMonthNum := year(Date_payment)*12 + month(Date_payment),
@curRef := Contact_reference
from payment
inner join (SELECT @consecStartDate := null,@curMonthNum := null,@consecStart := null,@curRef := null) as t
order by Contact_reference desc,Date_payment asc
) n
group by Contact_reference,consecStartDate;
```

Like I said - it won't give you the interval since last range end but I figured that part of an answer was better than none!

Comment: Wow! elegant, functional, and efficient. No worries on the interval since -- don't need it. Question: I'm new to using variables in select statements - and although I follow the logic throughout I'm lost as to why the `INNER JOIN (all vars := null) as t` is needed. Can you explain that voodoo? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The `INNER JOIN (all vars := null)` is simply a way of initialising all vars before using them in the 'SELECT' part of the query. Sort of like declaring and initialising them at the beginning of a class. You could achieve the same thing by removing the `INNER JOIN (all vars := null) as t` part and then run `SET all vars := null` before running the main query. It's nice to do it in one query if you can though ;-) The following link is a good ref for MySQL user defined variables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html